# Copy files over network if not present in any subfolder

Tags: sync, rsync

I have two machines, `nearbyMachine` and `remoteMachine`.

On `nearbyMachine`, files are being created in a folder.

```
nearbyMachine/
    myFiles/
        file1
        file2
        file3
        ...
```

I want to have the files on `remoteMachine` as well -- but sorted into directories:

```
remoteMachine/
    filesByCategory/
        loveLetters/
            file1
            file2
            ...
        otherLetters/
            file3
            ...
        ...
```

So I...

- Copy all the files from the folder to a temporary folder on `remoteMachine` over the Internet,
- Run a software on `remoteMachine` that removes all files from the temporary folder, that are already present in any subfolder of `filesByCategory`.
- Manually sort the files into existing or new subfolders of `filesByCategory`.

The problem: As time goes by, the first step takes more and more time. Hours. And it is *inelegant*.

Is there any way, for example with rsync, that I can copy only the files that are not already present anywhere on the remote machine? Or at least get a list of the files I have to copy?

In my understanding, all synchronization programs can only compare one single directory on both sides.

Comment: A bruteforce way is to use hard or softlinks so you can have a flattened folder on the target machine without taking up much space

Comment: Developing @Peter's idea, why not let `rsync` do its normal mirroring, then use links to create the additional, independent directory structure on the remote machine?

Comment: Hm, that *would have been an interesting idea*, if I had had it before I already had hundreds of files, sorted away in countless hours. :-(

Comment: Maybe syncing isn’t what you want. Why not copy files based on their modified / created date? New files will be copied. Old files will not.

Comment: A faster procedure would be to selectively copy to the temporary folder on remoteMachine only files that are newer than the last sync. Then you will only need to move a few files to their new folders. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc: This is interesting as well. The only thing I had to do would be to write down the sync date and make sure that *new files* have *new timestamps* as well...

Comment: Let me know if you would like an answer along these lines.

Comment: Of course :-) I am currently experimenting with md5-comparing bash scripts, but I do not think it will work out well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A faster procedure would be to selectively copy to the temporary folder on
`remoteMachine` only files that are newer than the last sync.
Then you will only need to sort a few files to their folders.

A simple script would do the job.
You would use a utility such as
[find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)
to list all the newer files. The `newerXY` parameter would perhaps be
useful, together with a reference file that your script will `touch`
at the end of the copy.

```
-newerXY reference
   Succeeds if timestamp X of the file being considered is newer
   than timestamp Y of the file reference.  The letters X and Y
   can be any of the following letters:

     a   The access time of the file reference
     B   The birth time of the file reference
     c   The inode status change time of reference
     m   The modification time of the file reference
     t   reference is interpreted directly as a time
```

The parameter to use may be `-newermm`.

Your script could use this list of files generated by `find` as the
parameter to a `cp` command, to copy to the remote server,
where you may sort them to their respective folders.